# Who needs dimensions anyway?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

This is half a question, as I have this 'sort of' thought through. Still, I'd like to have some confirmation. Here it goes:

From what I've seen so far, a group holds all the information necessary for a plot. Let's imagine a bar chart for the 'canonical' dc data array. We define a dimension on type and then a group. The group data will give us all the necessary coordinates for drawing the bars.

**Why do we need dimensions, then?** Is this for plotting, or just for keeping track of the filters and dynamically updating the chart?

Answer (score 0):

This is only half an answer. :)

Yes, there is some redundancy between dimensions and groups for sure.

1. The group key function needs to be a refinement of (and [must be consistent with](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#consistent-dimension-and-group-value-functions)) the dimension key function.
   There's only one place where I've found it's helpful to refine the group key function more than the dimension key function: when the dimension is time and the group is some quantization of time like months or hours. Otherwise there is no need to specify the group key function at all. I haven't seen too many people create sets of time-series charts where different charts are quantized at different levels, so I am not sure if that's the motivation.
2. Filtering happens through the dimension, not the group, and [a group does not observe its dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters) - so you might want them to be different objects so you that you can optionally have the chart respond to its own filters. That's pretty rare, though - usually a chart will read data from a group on the dimension it filters.

Any other reasons? Please add to this list!